# Convert file from assets folder in android to arraylist<hashmap<string,object>>

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, android-assets

I have a txt file which I have to get it in `arraylist<hashmap<string,object>>` format to use it in my code. So far I have used this code and I am getting string.

I have to add all the data to google maps. Any way to do this?

```
public String ReadFromfile(String fileName, Context context) {
                StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
                InputStream fIn = null;
                InputStreamReader isr = null;
                BufferedReader input = null;
                try {
                    fIn = context.getResources().getAssets()
                            .open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
                    input = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        returnString.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (isr != null)
                            isr.close();
                        if (fIn != null)
                            fIn.close();
                        if (input != null)
                            input.close();
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.getMessage();
                    }
                }
                return returnString.toString();
            }
```

Comment: what is the content and format of the txt file??

Comment: the format I have stored is arraylist<hashmap<string,object>> and its stored as test.txt

Comment: you serialized arraylist<hashmap<string,object>>??

Comment: I have converted json to arraylist<hashmap<string,object>> in android and saved it into test.txt .Is that serialized ?

Comment: you can store json itself. Using GSON a json string into java object.

Comment: how can I do that ? SOrry I have never used GSON before

Comment: post your json that you want to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json:

```
{
"name": "Something",
"age":24
}
```

Java class:

```
class Person{
private String name;
private int age;

getter and setters
}
```

Download GSON jar and add it to your project.

```
Person p=new Gson().fromJson("{'name':'something','age':23}",Person.class);

String sterPerson=new Gson().toJson(p);
```

Comment: I have a very complicated and nest json and I would like to load polygons in google maps by parsing json and the types of polygons differ .How can I do that ?Thanks for your time Vipul.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately what you want is JSONArray. A Collection of JSONObject. JSONObject is nothing but a form of Key Value Pair.

Basically , You can store data in file in the form of JSONArray.

For Ex :

```
[
           {"key","value"},
           {"key","value"},
           {"key","value"},
           {"key","value"}
]
```

Read more about

- JSONArray : http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html
- JSONObject : http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html